Is this fiberglass insulation and is it okay that it's sticking up a bit? Look like it's all over the underside of my stove door
Is this fiberglass insulation and is it okay that it's sticking up a bit? Looks like it's all over the underside of my stove door. As it's very sparkly. I've been having weird fibers around my house and am trying to rule this oven out as a cause.



